# Django doesn't use pyodbc as python does

Tags: python, django, pyodbc

I have a python script using pyodbc to read a 2005 sql server database:

```
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=schema;UID=user;PWD=pass')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(str.format("SELECT id FROM schema.dbo.mytable WHERE num = {0}", foo.num)
```

This works fine.

When I try to configure a database in my django project settings with the same parameters, I can't read tables from the same database.

```
'second_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'schema',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'servername',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server',
        },
    },
```

Somewhere in django project workspace:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(str.format("SELECT id FROM schema.dbo.mytable WHERE num = {0}", obj.num)
```

I get:

```
[42S02] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'schema.dbo.mytable'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)
```

Can anyone help me to detect what's the difference between both? Django is running in the same machine where I run the script, so I believe it isn't a permissions problem...

I would like to use the django connections instead of define a standard cursor, because I prefer to have all the database settings within the django settings, not spread out around the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally my problem was that I wanted to open a cursor from a secondary db, not the default one, so the mistake was here:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

It should be:

```
from django.db import connections  # instead of connection
cursor = connections['second_db'].cursor()  # using the proper db
```

Answer (score 1):

Django's execute format is slightly different. Try this?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM schema.dbo.mytable WHERE num = %s", [obj.num])
```

This will also eliminate a possible SQL Injection attack vector. You probably also want to change your `pyodbc` query to use bound parameters:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM schema.dbo.mytable WHERE num = ?", foo.num)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I found the problem trying your suggestions.